# httpservletrequest is null when http-only is set to true

Tags: session, jboss7.x, httponly

I am using JBoss 7 and I have configure my session config in web.xml as follows:

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>240</session-timeout>
<http-only>true</http-only>
</session-config>
```

However, in my servlet, i am getting a nullpointerexception when I try to retrieve the current session as follows:

```
request.getSession(false);
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

That seems correct per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)).

Snippet:

```
Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.

If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method returns null.
```

After looking again at your `web.xml` snippet, it's not quite correct. The `<http-only/>` is not part of the `<session-config/>`. Move it into `<cookie-config/>` as per the following:

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>240</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Thanks James. I am able to retrieve a valid session if I do NOT have <http-only> as true in my web.xml. Why is it that there's no session when <http-only> is true?

Comment: I am setting the session attribute in a jsp file as follows "session.setAttribute("fileName", fileName)". I am also setting this attribute in the httpservletrequest object as "request.setAttribute("fileName", fileName)". However, in my java code, when I do "request.getSession(false)", I get a null session. And when I do "request.getAttribute("fileName"), I still get null. This is the behaviour I am seeing when I set <http-only> to true in web.xml. Works fine when I remove the <http-only> from my web.xml. Am I missing anything? Thanks for your help James